# how to retrieve data from many to many relationship in mvc c# with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an c# mvc project where have the search filter form. Also have 2 tables many-to-many relationships for table table_a and table_c. 
and i want to get value_table_c in table_c **linq** mvc

```
table_a
------------
id_table_a
desc_table_a
-------------

table_b
------------
id_table_b
desc_table_b
------------

table_c
------------
id_table_a
id_table_b
value_table_c
-------------

SELECT 
    table_c.value_table_c
FROM table_c
JOIN table_a ON table_a.id_table_a = table_c.id_table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_b.id_table_b = table_c.id_table_b
WHERE table_a.id_table_a=1;
```

Somebody have any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please mention the relationships and desired output.

Comment: i want to get value_table_c in table_c.

Comment: do you want this query to be converted in linq?

Comment: Why even join table_a and table_b if you can go for table_c directly? Do you need something Special from one of those 2 tables?

Comment: @VarunVasishtha : yes, i want this query convert into LINQ

Comment: @MarcelB : i want value only from table c, but in MVC many to many relationship table so far i cant go table_c directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    table_c.value_table_c
FROM table_c
JOIN table_a ON table_a.id_table_a = table_c.id_table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_b.id_table_b = table_c.id_table_b
WHERE table_a.id_table_a=1;
```

to linq

```
var res = (from c in context.table_c
           join a in context.table_a on c.id_table_a = a.id_table_a 
           join b in context.table_b on c.id_table_b = b.id_table_b
           where a.id_table_a = 1
           select new 
           {
               c.value_table_c
           })
```

Usually you would "select new" into a known type.

But that is how you would do a Inner join linq version of your SQL

Comment: FYI you probably need to Add .SingleOrDefault() at the end

Comment: in my project, don't have context table_c (many to many relationship table)

Comment: @kangdadang hi im not sure i follow... you provided the SQL, if the SQL is incorrect then update it accordingly. You need to update to your table names and context names...., if you not seeing what your looking for then you need to tell us what you do see.

Comment: if you can run that SQL and it works... then, it mean you need to update your EF models to support the actual table structure, if the linq is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code I am considering 'db' is the object name of entity database context.

```
db.table_c.where(c=>c.table_a != null && c.table_a.id_table_a = 1).select(c=>c.value_table_c)
```

I am not sure why you are joining 'table_b' because you are not applying any filter and you are not selecting any value from it. But if the mentioned sql  query is your requirement then this linq query will help you and I am also assuming that both tablea and b has reference keys.

Comment: in my project, i cant access db.table_c, only db.table_a and db.table_b

Comment: to get table _b i, usually use this linq  -->  db.table_b.Where(w => w.table_a.Any(r => r.id_table_a == 1)).ToList();